# `system()` can't get output of shell command in vimrc

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I want to enable some configurations only when the distribution is Fedora. Here is my code.

```
let s:os = system("sed -n 's/^NAME=\(.*\)/\1/p' /etc/os-release")
echo s:os
if s:os == "Fedora"
        " some configurations
endif
```

This snippet doesn't work and the `s:os` is an empty string. However, the sed command works well when I run it in shell directly. I don't know why it doesn't work in vimrc.

Comment: Double all backslashes or switch to using single-quoted strings.

Comment: @Matt Many thanks. Save my life!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble you're having is with the backslashes inside the string (as @Matt correctly pointed out in the comments.)

Vim strings (using double-quotes as delimiters) interpret the backslash as a special character, so you need to escape them with an additional backslash if you want to use them in a double-quoted string.

```
let s:os = system("sed -n 's/^NAME=\\(.*\\)/\\1/p' /etc/os-release")
```

Alternatively, you might want to use single-quoted strings in Vim, since those do not treat the backslash as special and don't require escaping it. This is pretty fine in this particular case, since using double-quotes for the sed expression in the shell command is OK, since they do not contain any shell metacharacters such as `$`:

```
let s:os = system('sed -n "s/^NAME=\(.*\)/\1/p" /etc/os-release')
```

On the other hand, you could actually do that same operation using Vimscript primitives only, which should be more efficient (since you're not spawning a couple of external processes anymore) and more portable (since it doesn't depend on which particular shell you're using or whether a `sed` can even be found in `$PATH`.)

Consider using the following snippet instead:

```
let s:os = matchlist(readfile('/etc/os-release'), '^NAME=\(.*\)')[1]
```

See [`:help readfile()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#readfile%28%29) and [`:help matchlist()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#matchlist%28%29).

You might want to add some error handling, in case the file doesn't exist or the variable match can't be found there.

Answer (score 3):

@Matt is absolutely right; you might use double backslashes:

```
let s:os = system("sed -n 's/^NAME=\\(.*\\)/\\1/p' /etc/os-release")
```

or switch to a single-quoted string:

```
let s:os = system('sed -n "s/^NAME=\(.*\)/\1/p" /etc/os-release')
```

But here's a tidbit: [Here documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) are also available as of [vim 8.1.1362](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/c79745a82faeb5a6058e915ca49a4c69fa60ea01):

```
let s:command =<< trim END
    sed -n "s/^NAME=\(.*\)/\1/p" /etc/os-release
END
let s:os = system(s:command[0])
```

See [`:help :let-heredoc`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-heredoc) for more information.

Happy Vimming!